# Oracle. Parameters in query. Wrong name/number of the variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, ado.net, plsql

My code:

```
oracleCom.CommandText = @"declare P_ID tbl_objects.i_id%TYPE;
                          BEGIN
                            UPDATE tbl_objects
                            SET i_status_id = 234
                            WHERE s_code = '" + objectsChanged[j] + 
                            @"' RETURNING i_id INTO P_ID;
                                :param_id := P_ID;
                          END;";
oracleCom.Parameters.Add("param_id", OracleType.Number).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
try
{
    oracleCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch
{----------}
```

The compiler generates an error:
Wrong name/number of the variable.
But when i use this sql in pl/sql developer everything works correctly.

This code work correctly:

```
OracleCommand oracleCom = new OracleCommand
{
   Connection = oraConnect,
   CommandText = @"declare P_ID tbl_objects.i_id%TYPE;
                   BEGIN insert into tbl_objects
                                (s_code, i_status_id)
                                values
                                (:s_code, 234)
                      RETURNING I_ID INTO :p_id;
                   END;"
};
```

Comment: If it's a compiler error, as opposed to a runtime error, it means that there's something wrong in the Java code as opposed to something being wrong in the PL/SQL string.  What line does the compiler indicate has an error?

Comment: In PL/DEVELOPER it works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OracleCommand` can't handle stored procedure with multiple lines. You have to change your `CommandText` to be in one line. (Just remove all the new lines).

I personally have a method that replaces new lines with spaces so I can store my commands formatted but i "flatten" them before putting them into `OracleCommand`.

Comment: Code which i added in end of question work correctly

Answer (score 0):

It might just be a minor mistake. Instead of:

```
:param_id = P_ID;
```

it should be:

```
:param_id := P_ID;
```

(assignment instead of equality operator).

Comment: I corrected this line. But it didn't help me.